# How to change the color of last Element in array - js

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in my following Code:

```js
let textPos = document.getElementById('js-headline');
let i = 0;

function typewriter() {
  let letters = ['C', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'X'];
  if (i < letters.length) {
    textPos.innerText += letters[i];
    i++;
    setTimeout(typewriter, 1000);
  } else if (i == letters.length) {
    let lastLetter = letters[letters.length - 1];
    lastLetter.style.color = 'red';
  }
}

typewriter();
```

in my "else if" I select the last element of my array and I like to change the color but it doesn't work - I get an error message

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'color')".

And one thing is crazy, I can put the last element of this array in an alert Box or in a console.log and it shows me the last element...

Comment: an index starts at 0, so you need your if conditional to be `(i < letters.length - 1)` and your else if conditional to be `(i == letters.length - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `.style.color` property of a string, which is impossible. You need to make a `<span>` element to be able to change the color, and add the `<span>` instead of the letter itself.

Also, your conditionals for finding the last element is wrong, so I fixed that too.

```js
let textPos = document.getElementById("js-headline");
let i = 0;
function typewriter() {
        let letters = ["C", "o", "d", "e", "X"];
        if(i < letters.length - 1) {
        textPos.innerText += letters[i];
        i++;
        setTimeout(typewriter, 1000);
    }
    else {
        let lastLetter = letters[letters.length - 1];
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerText = lastLetter;
        span.style.color = "red";
        textPos.appendChild(span);
    }
}
typewriter();
```

```html
<h1 id="js-headline"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of array items starts from 0 so when you say `i == letters.length` that property doesn't exist of array the last index on array is equal to `letters.length - 1`

you need to change the code to following:

```js
let textPos = document.getElementById('js-headline');
let i = 0;

function typewriter() {
  let letters = ['C', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'X'];
  if (i < letters.length - 1) {
    textPos.innerText += letters[i];
    i++;
    setTimeout(typewriter, 1000);
  } else if (i == letters.length - 1) {
    let lastLetter = letters[letters.length - 1];
    lastLetter.style.color = 'red';
  }
}

typewriter();
```

I hope it helped

### Edit:

a little more about array indexing

for example in the following array the indexing is like below:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
              ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
              |    |    |    |    |
              0    1    2    3    4
```

when you call `array.length` it will return the number of elements in array but the first index starts from 0

Comment: This still has the problem of trying to set the `.style.color` property of a string, which is impossible

Answer (score 0):

I hope this demonstration of an alternative typewriter function helps!

```js
async function typewrite(word, ele) {
  const letters = [...word];
  const lastLetter = letters.pop();
  for (letter of letters) {
    ele.textContent += letter;
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
  }
  const aSpan = document.createElement("span");
  aSpan.style.color = "red";
  aSpan.textContent = lastLetter;
  ele.appendChild(aSpan);
}

typewrite("Hello World!", document.querySelector("#output"));
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```